# Is there any known dynamical process to obtain supertubes?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, supergravity

I'm looking for a dynamical process to produce [supertubes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0103030).

For example, microstates of the D1-D5 black hole system can be understood as supertubes. See, for example, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512053 and references therein. Getting more precise understanding of this phenomena (supertubes as black hole microstates), I thought that knowing this dynamical process is important. But I couldn't find any relevant references. So my question is that **is there any known dynamical process of getting supertubes?**